# Add-on is not responding. Wait or cancel?

Tags: cloud, confluence, add-on, atlassian-connect

I am trying to make a simple HelloWorld add-on using atlassian-connect-play-java :

[image]

My Controller :

```
package controllers;
import views.html.*;
import com.atlassian.connect.play.java.controllers.AcController;
import com.google.common.base.Supplier;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
public class Application extends Controller {
     public static Result index()
    {
        return AcController.index(home(), descriptor());
    }
     private static Supplier<Result> descriptor()
    {
        return new Supplier<Result>()
        {
            @Override
            public Result get()
            {
                return AcController.descriptor();
            }
        };
    }
    private static Supplier<Result> home()
    {
        return new Supplier<Result>()
        {
            @Override
            public Result get()
            {
                return ok(index.render("Hello"));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

My routes file :

```
GET / controllers.Application.index()
GET /assets/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
-> / ac.Routes
```

My index:scala.html file :

```
@(message: String)
@main("Welcome to Play") {
        <p>@message</p>

}
```

My main.scala.html file :

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>

        <script src="http://localhost:1990/confluence/atlassian-connect/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/5.4.3/css/aui.css" media="all">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ac-content">
        <p>@content</p>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

My atlassian-connect.json file :

```
{
     "key": "${addonKey}",
     "name": "${addonName}",
     "description": "Atlassian Connect add-on",

     "baseUrl": "${localBaseUrl}",
     "vendor": {
        "name": "Atlassian",
        "url": "http://www.atlassian.com"
    },
     "authentication": {
         "type": "none"
     },

     "modules": {
    "generalPages": [
      {
        "url": "/",
        "key": "test-application",
        "location": "system.user",
        "name": {
          "value": "Test"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "scopes": ["READ"]
 }
```

When running my play application, it all works fine.

But when I install my plugin on a local instance of Confluence and launch it, the add-on's content never stops loading, I get the following message :

Add-on is not responding. wait or cancel ?

I tried to find the problem but I couldn't, can someone please help ?

Answer (score 5):

All Atlassian Connect add-ons require the `all.js` Javascript resource to be loaded, so it can create the bridge between your add-on and the host environment. The loader sits there and waits for the bridge to be established. This means you aren't including `all.js`.

An example of doing: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/whoslooking-connect/src/9066821fe168737b94d5b1e8ad520befb200ec99/app/views/poller.scala.html?at=master#cl-43

Double check the console of your browser for errors though if this doesn't fix your issues. It will likely give a hint as to what the problem is. Also check the network tab (maybe with a reload) to make sure all your resources load.

Some frameworks also emit a `X-Frame-Origin: SAMEORIGIN` header by default causing the browser to never load the content of the iframe. This should not be the case with atlassian-connect-play.

Comment: Yep, had to put this in the head: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/atlassian-connect/all.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you for this insight! The url I ended up using was https://connect-cdn.atl-paas.net/all.js - The tutorials all reference a variable named `hostScriptUrl` in the hbs templates. If you run one of the samples and see what `hostScriptUrl` resolves to, its `https://connect-cdn.atl-paas.net/all.js`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your response :)

The url that I specified in the descriptor was invalid. A simple "/" or an empty url "" was not accepted by confluence so I had to change it to "/home" and change my routes file as well.